# Phonegap Can't Redirecting to a page

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, redirect

So I have this form where upon submission I do a SQL query and redirect it to another page. But when I try to test this on the android tablet it doesnt redirect, nor does it error meaning the SQL call is valid and works...can someone please help me out

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="oneSection">
      <form method="post" action="" id="barcodeForm">
        Barcode: <br/>
        <input name="barcode" id="barcode" type="text" class="sub"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" class="open" id="before" value="SUBMIT" onclick="check()" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function check() {
      var barcode = $('#barcode').val();
      if(barcode.length <= 0) {
        $('#barcode').css('border', '2px solid red');
        e.preventDefault();
        return;
      } else {
      alert(barcode.length);
        var barcode = $('#barcode').val();
        checkBarcode(false, barcode);
      }
    }

function checkBarcode(doAuto, id) {
  var successCall;
  if (doAuto) {
    successCall = function (tx, result) {
      var item = result.rows.item(0);
      $('[name="client"]').val(item['cname']);
      $('[name="address"]').val(item['address']);
      $('[name="sitename"]').val(item['sname']);
      $('[name="model"]').val(item['model']);
      $('[name="lasttested"]').val(item['ltest']);
      $('[name="nounits"]').val(item['units']);
      $('[name="comments"]').val(item['comments']);
    }
  } else {
    test.innerHTML += 'at the start<br/>';
    successCall = function () {
      var URL = 'test.html?id=' + id;
      window.location.href = URL;
    }
  }

  var queryDB = function queryDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(getBarcode, [id], successCall, onError);
  }
  db.transaction(queryDB, onError);
}

  </script>
```

What happens at the moment is that it submit's the input value and resets the form without forwarding the page or anything...